# How to publish a Asp.Net Core 2.2 app in debug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, publish

I am developing a Asp.net core 2.2 app. I want to publish a test build to test on a local machine. But when I click on the Exe it created I get this error:

> It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>
> The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.

But when I create a different publish profile for Release but with the same settings it just works.

I don't know why this is happening.

**ToFolderDebug profile**

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>6fd2ee03-2f15-49f8-ad17-c40e5c264add</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>false</_IsPortable>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**ToFolderRelease profile**

```
Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>6fd2ee03-2f15-49f8-ad17-c40e5c264add</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Is dotnet core RUNTIME installed on your machine? :)

Comment: @DoctorPrisme: It's self-contained.

Comment: @DoctorPrisme it is self-contained and yes I installed runtime on the test server before I started testing

Comment: Is there any demo project to reproduce your issue? I made a test with built-in Asp.Net Core MVC template, it works correctly with Debug and Relase publish profile.

Comment: @TaoZhou i fixed by deleting all the files in the publish directory and republishing